# How to track the last entered character in a TextField?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am creating a form and I need to track the last character entered. I know I can use **onChange** to detect when the text field changed, but it displays the while string and not just the last character. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddAssetView: View {
    @State private var costTextField = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Cost", text: $costTextField)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                            .onChange(of: costTextField, perform: { value in
                                print(value)
                            })
                    }
                }.navigationTitle(Text("Enter a new item"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried importing UITextField and using its delegate methods?

Comment: *but it displays the while string and not just the last character* - this part is not clear, would you elaborate more on what do you try to achieve?

Comment: @Asperi he probably meant WHOLE string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with just using at [String.last](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893970-last) ?

Comment: Is there any way you can tell if they hit the back space? Or is there another way to capture that?

Comment: Compare the previous value with the new one? If it's shorter, the user pressed backspace.

Comment: Because the last entered character may be actually inserted in the middle of a string